# How to change keyboard after setup?

Tags: system-installation, 19.04

I setup Ubuntu 19.04, however I did not do the keyboard detection option. Now I get a “ charter each time I enter the @.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a shell terminal and use the command

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

From the [man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/dpkg-reconfigure.8.html):

> dpkg-reconfigure reconfigures packages after they have already been installed. Pass it the
>          names of a package or packages to reconfigure. It will ask configuration questions, much
>          like when the package was first installed.